# Using $_GET with pagination shows same posts

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm using `$_GET` to update some variables for my search results but when I click to the next page of results it just shows me the same posts again from page 1. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $carigot = $_GET['car'];
    $searchm = $_GET['s'];
}
?>

<?php

$custom_query_args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'CurrentLocation',
            'value'   => $searchm,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'CarIWant',
            'value'   => $carigot,
            'type'    => '',
            'compare' => '=',
                ),
    ),
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1,
);

 $custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args ); 

$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query; 

if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
        $custom_query->the_post();
      get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'excerpt' );
    endwhile;
endif;
// Reset postdata
wp_reset_postdata();

next_posts_link( 'Next', $custom_query->max_num_pages ); 
previous_posts_link( 'Previous' );


 $wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your query. Notice you call `new WP_Query` twice and assign it to the same variable. Move your pagination to the original and get rid of that second one.

```
$custom_query_args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => '1',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'CurrentLocation',
                'value'   => $searchm,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'CarIWant',
                'value'   => $carigot,
                'type'    => '',
                'compare' => '=',
                    ),
        ),
        'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1,
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I changed my code like you said but the problem is still there. I edited my post above to show the code I'm using now. Did I do everything you said correctly?